# Why table content is not getting displayed in XSLT template?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to understand appliying templates in XSLT.
This is the code

```
<!-- Datos de ejemplo -->
<personas>
  <persona>
    <nombre>John Doe</nombre>
    <edad>30</edad>
  </persona>
  <persona>
    <nombre>Jane Smith</nombre>
    <edad>25</edad>
  </persona>
  <!-- Agrega más personas aquí si es necesario -->
</personas>

<!-- Plantilla XSLT -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Edad</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="personas/persona" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="persona">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="nombre" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="edad" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why the content of the table is not in the table?

I tried adding more content to the table, I trie to give a style to the table but nothing.

Comment: You should provide more information about what you're doing, the tools you're using and the results. To apply the XSLT transformation to an XML source you should use an XSLT processor such as your web browser's built-in XSLT engine. If you're having a hard time explaining your question in English, you could give [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) a try.

Comment: When `personas` is really the `root`-element of the `xml` and this xml has `no namespaces`, your xslt should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me at [an online fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%21--%20Plantilla%20XSLT%20--%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%221.0%22%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chtml%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3ENombre%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3EEdad%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22personas%2Fpersona%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22persona%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22nombre%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22edad%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3C%21--%20Datos%20de%20ejemplo%20--%3E%0D%0A%3Cpersonas%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cpersona%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cnombre%3EJohn%20Doe%3C%2Fnombre%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cedad%3E30%3C%2Fedad%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fpersona%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cpersona%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cnombre%3EJane%20Smith%3C%2Fnombre%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cedad%3E25%3C%2Fedad%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fpersona%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%21--%20Agrega%20m%C3%A1s%20personas%20aqu%C3%AD%20si%20es%20necesario%20--%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fpersonas%3E&input-type=XML). Consider to edit your question and explain in more details how you are trying to run the code and how it fails.